# Recommended way to share pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a set of visualization tools.  All the data sources have different characteristics, and the data is useful by itself, so I'm building individual front ends.  Each tool stores its data in HDF5 via pandas.  However, I do want the tools to cooperate, so that if they do have timeframes and data sources that overlap, the data can be included in other tools.  Is there a recommended way of sharing pandas dataframes, so that when I export it on one system and import it into another, nothing is lost?

to_json doesn't work, based on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9146.  There are some references to in other places saying that CSVs aren't guaranteed to export/import equivalently, either.  I'm looking at to_html, possibly, but some of the dataframes have multiindexes, and I'm not sure how well that will work.  But I don't see any recommended ways of sharing data in the pandas doc, so I'm not sure if there is something people have found to work better than others.

Comment: Have you tried df.to_pickle() or df.to_msgpack()?

Comment: what about `df.to_hdf`?

Comment: Yes, I was going to try to_msgpack() next, but I was wondering if there was any consensus on the best way to do this.  I couldn't find anything anywhere I looked/searched, so I thought I'd ask, especially regarding whether or not any of the methods were guaranteed to import the same way they exported.

Comment: I think hdf would probably be the most standard and recommended way to go unless you have a reason not to use it (and csv probably the least recommended way).  But the responsibility is always on you to check the data integrity after writing out and reading in, regardless of how you do it.  You can never assume this will work 100% reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, I ended up going with to_msgpack; right now, you can't write a dataframe out to a file handle (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10491).  There is a workaround available, but I'd prefer not to have to use that when I can use to_msgpack directly to a file handle.